# Posting action/data to Twitter Bootstrap logout button

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap (TWBS) to build my UI, and am having trouble figuring out how to post data when NOT using a form. I have essentially take TWBS's template and tried to edit it.  I am trying to send a "logout" value back to my index.php page which should sniff out the value and log out the user.  My code in the HTML:

```
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="./" type="submit" name="action" value="logout" method="post">Sign Out</a></li>
          <li><a href= "./"
            <form method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="logout">Sign Out
            </a></form>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

As you can see I also tried to mimic a form to post the action, but that's not working either.  Back in the php code, the "sniffer" is:

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'logout')
{
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['loggedIn']);
unset($_SESSION['email']);
unset($_SESSION['password']);
header('Location: .'); 
exit();
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Twine

Comment: FWIW, you can name read the value or label of your submit button if it has name, the "submitted action" will be posted as well, that would help get rid of the hidden field

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Bootstrap, which is just CSS + a bit of JS.

Forms are meant to format HTTP requests based on user input values - in this case you just need a link:

```
<a href="index.php?action=logout">Logout</a>
```

If you want to fancy style it in Bootstrap, add something like:

```
<a href="index.php?action=logout" class="btn btn-primary">Logout</a>
```

By the way, you pass actions to your php script just via `POST` method - you'd better refer to `$_REQUEST` array, then make decisions based on `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` if any.

Comment: moonwave9 thanks.  While this is sending the logout request to my index page, it's not sending the user to index.php (a landing page when the user is not logged in). This is keeping me on the same page as where the logout button was appearing.

Comment: It depends on your PHP script - the logout action should end with `header("Location: index.php?action=home")`, or how you call your homepage action.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('soForm').submit()">Sign Out</a></li>
          <li>"
            <form id="form" id="soForm" action="/" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="logout">Sign Out
            </form>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Your issue is that a tags are not form elements so you have to use js to trigger the submit action of the form.

Check out W3CSchools for info on the form and a tags to see what they can actually do.

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'logout')
{
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['loggedIn']);
unset($_SESSION['email']);
unset($_SESSION['password']);
header('Location: /'); 
exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out.  However, the code above is still not working. When clicking the logout dropdown field, I remain on the page (if I logout, I should be brought to a new user landing page).  I have also output the _POST array and it indicates that it is empty.

Comment: Did you try changing the location header header("Location: .") looks suspicious "." usually means current maybe try /

Comment: j_mcnally - the . seems to be the one to use.  Slash isn't helping on this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use only the form ? In this case, you don't really have to pretend and you can use the form :

```
<li>
    <form method="post" action="./">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="logout" />
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Out" />
    </form>
</li>
```

If you want a more complex button, you can use this instead and put html in it.

```
<button type="submit"><i class="icon-user"></i> Sign out</button>
```

BTW, this is doesn't depend on Twitter Bootstrap. You can use that wherever you have HTML.

Comment: Sherbow, thanks. I tried this, and while the behavior is doing what I want - logging out the user and returning to the landing page, this is creating a button that I don't want.  I am trying to use the "dropdown-menu" class in TWBS.  You can see the code in my original post.  I feel close on this, but still not quite there.